# Web service frameworks for Java 1.4?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, java1.4

We want to implement web services on our Weblogic 8.1 Java 1.4 application.  We want to create new server services and call services in other apps.  And we need to stick with Java 1.4 (for now).

Due to 1.4 we can't use frameworks like Restlet or Jersey.  Are there any good web service (preferably REST) API frameworks that support Java 1.4?

We could do a home grown solution if necessarily.  Ie: just setup servlets on the server side and on the client side just use something like [`HttpURLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 1):

Java 1.4 is EOL since 2006. REST become a 'hype' since around 2008.

Almost no one API/framework builder is going to support EOL'ed products, so don't expect much.

You can however homegrow one yourself. It's basically easy to do with help of a `Filter`.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) prior to version 1.5 should do the work with Java 1.4 and supports REST

Comment: Good suggestion. Is Axis just a web service client API (calling web services)?  Does it also help setting up server web services?

Comment: No it's not just a calling Web Services, you can use it to provide (server side) services as well

Answer (score 1):

Try again Restlet with Retrotranslator as suggested by the lead developer.

http://www.mail-archive.com/discuss@restlet.tigris.org/msg07163.html

Comment: Good point.  I've never used Retrotranslater. Makes me nervous (for no good reason)

Answer (score 0):

NetKernel 3 requires only Java 1.4.2. It can be embedded as a Servlet in your configuration. Here is a [case study](http://1060research.com/customers/case_studies/trimondo/) that describes this usage.