# How to call webservice using Java 1.4

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, webservice-client

The webservice is already created and we have to consume it in our web application, which is in Java 1.4.

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but Java 1.4.... seriously? Why? Java 1.4 should be dead since 2006. That's 7 years ago.

Comment: Check especially this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1712144/7918.

Comment: Yes. But the application which we are using is developed at 2004 . So we are doing some inhancement work on it.